# Putting element last in linked list c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, element

I would like to get some help on how I should write this add() function on how to put the elements in the last spot of the list. It looks like this at the moment:

I've edited it and have my class up now:

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        template <class T>
        class List;

        template <class T>
        class Node {
        public:
          Node ( T *t) : data(t), next(0) {}
          ~Node();
        private:
          T *data;
          Node* next;
          friend class List<T>;
        };

        template <class T>

        class Predicate {
         public:
          Predicate() {}
          virtual bool operator()( const T& v) = 0;
        };

        template <class T>
        class List {
        public:
          List() : first(new Node<T>(T())) {} //"dummy"-nod först

          void add( T *t );
          void remove_if( T t );
          void remove_if( Predicate<T> &pred );
          void print();  // skriver alla elementen inom "måsvingar"

        private:  
          Node<T> *first;
        };
```

In my main I have:

```
   int main()
    List<int> intlista;
      intlista.add( new int(1) );
      intlista.add( new int(2) );
      intlista.add( new int(3) );
      intlista.add( new int(2) );
      intlista.add( new int(4) );
      intlista.add( new int(5) );
      intlista.add( new int(6) );
```

Comment: Best help is, try to use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: How is ``Node`` implemented? For this to be linked list, ``Node`` would need to contain a pointer to the next ``Node``. Adding an element to the back could then either be done by traversing those pointers, or by additionally keeping a pointer to the last element in the ``List`` class.

Comment: @amaurea I've edited the main post so you can see for yourself :)

Comment: Show us what you have done. Give it a go. You don't learn programming by pressing CTRL-C / CTRL-V and some mouse clicks and drags.

Comment: @MarketingMark Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions, and please don't ask us to fix your code, this is a Q&A site, which is different from a help desk or a forum.

Answer (score 3):

Starting at the first node of the list, follow the `next` node until you find one that is NULL. Create a new node, and assign it to that `next`.

> first->next->next->next->... next->NULL

then

> first->next->next->next->... next->new_node->NULL

Comment: can you explain what you mean further?

Comment: Instead of asking lots of questions, please post something that you have written. Even if it has no chance of working, it will (hopefully) explain what part of this you don't understand.

Comment: @MarketingMark you have a linked list. Start at the beginning, follow the nodes via the links until you get to the last one, then add a "next" node to that. If this is confusing, then you should probably take a step back and have a look at what a linked list is conceptually.